# OpenCV with Ecplise

Tags: eclipse, opencv, ubuntu, gcc, eclipse-cdt

I have tested and worked my ubuntu 12.04 64 bit system with OpenCV and cmake/make interface but, now i want to use OpenCV with Ecplipse like [enter link description here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_eclipse/linux_eclipse.html).

my

```
pkg-config --cflags opencv
```

output is

```
-I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include
```

and
   pkg-config --libs opencv
output is

```
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_contrib.so         /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_features2d.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_flann.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_gpu.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_legacy.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ml.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_nonfree.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_objdetect.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_photo.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_stitching.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ts.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_video.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videostab.so
```

I set my project like tutorial said but whenever i tried to build project i've got

```
make all 
Building file: ../src/OpenCVTryOut.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -I/usr/local/include/opencv2 -I/usr/local/include -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/OpenCVTryOut.d" -MT"src/OpenCVTryOut.d" -o "src/OpenCVTryOut.o" "../src/OpenCVTryOut.cpp"
Finished building: ../src/OpenCVTryOut.cpp

Building target: OpenCVTryOut
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++ -L/usr/local/lib -o "OpenCVTryOut"  ./src/OpenCVTryOut.o   -llibopencv_highgui -llibopencv_imgproc -llibopencv_core
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibopencv_highgui
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibopencv_imgproc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibopencv_core
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [OpenCVTryOut] Error 1
    **** Build Finished ****
```

I dont know where i'm missing but it confuse me lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would You not want to import a make project to eclipse? Or use cmake eclipse projects generator? It can be a bit tricky sometimes, but frees You from tying to eclipse for ever ever ever with Your project :)

Oh, and try without `lib` parts in library names like `-lopencv_core`